# lookup value multiple comma separated from one cell

Tags: vlookup

**In my excel sheet, Tab1 has this: 

Col A   Col B** 
Red     135 
Green   231 
Blue    776
 
**Tab2 has this: 

Col A       Col B** 
Red,Green   366 
Blue,Red    911

I would like to have the formula to auto calculate Col B value in Tab2. Any hint for that, thanks so much.

Comment: You could consider a vlookup on each split value and then sum the 2 vlookups together

Comment: Tab2 has lot of combination. Sum all Col A in Tab2 and output to Col B.

Comment: You mean there are more than 2 colour combinations? So maybe 3 or more colours on column A?

Comment: I know something like "=SUM(LOOKUP({2,2,3}, {1,2,3,4;511,512,513,514}))"

but i can not apply it into  this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the data are started at cell A1 for each tab.

Try this at column B of Tab2:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND('Tab1'!$A$1:$A$3,$A2))*1,'Tab1'!$B$1:$B$3)`